# How to get Spring MVC to populate a field in a request parameter object that refers to an entity by id

Tags: spring-mvc, data-binding

Say I have two entity classes:

```
@Entity
class EntityA 
{
     @Id
     @Column
     private int id;
     @Column
     private String name
}
@Entity
class EntityB
{
     @Id
     @Column
     private int id;
     @Column
     private String description;
     @Column
     private EntityA entityA;
}
```

Now assume I have a controller that accepts an `EntityB` as an argument:

```
@RequestMethod("/DoSomethingWithAnEntityB")
public ModelAndView doSomething (EntityB entityB, BindingResult bindingResult)
{
     // ...
}
```

How can I configure Spring MVC so that it is able to resolve the reference contained in EntityB to the EntityA by id.  For example, if the database contains an EntityA with value `{id: 42, name: "The Answer"}` and my request contains the query string `description=How+many+roads+must+a+man+walk+down&entityA=42`, how do I configure Spring so that my method gets a parameter with the appropriate values:

```
{
  id: 0, 
  description: "How many roads must a man walk down", 
  entityA: { 
    id: 42, 
    name: "The Answer"
  }
}
```

As suggested in the comments below, I can see that this might involve the use of a method with the `@ModelAttribute` annotation, but how can I make that work when I have some methods that produce an `EntityA` by specifying the id of an existing one, and others that specify the entire entity content explicitly (e.g. to create a new one or update an existing one)?

Comment: if you are using the xml configuration , you need to add <beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"> 
 </beans:bean> in your configuration file and dependency in pom.xml <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
</dependency>

Comment: If I understood correctly you're trying to bind a composite object, if that is the case it can be done easily with model attribute in Spring MVC, and if you're using JSP, then you'll need also to use the form tag library. hope this helps.

Comment: @MosheArad - Yes, that's what I'm trying to do.  But I still don't quite see how or where to put the code that's necessary to convert the value "entityA=42" into the actual entity, which involves calling out to a database to retrieve the entity.  Obviously Spring can't do that without configuration of some kind, but I just can't quite figure out from the documentation where that configuration needs to go.  I think it may involve `@ModelAttribute` as you suggest, but how does that work alongside other requests that might need to specify the content of an `EntityA` explicitly rather than by id?

Comment: Spring will do the conversion for you. Spring will take the details from your form and will data bind it to your parameter in your controller.  Do you need an example?

Comment: @MosheArad It needs to pull in data from the database somehow.  It can't do that unless I tell it how.  How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you need to pull data from your DB? didn't you talked about how to data bind data from JSP form to your parameter in the controller? you said yes.

Comment: Yes.  But one of the fields being supplied by the JSP is the id of the entity to be embedded in the parameter being constructed, rather than the entire content of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147990/discussion-between-moshe-arad-and-jules).

Comment: Note: a similar question (which doesn't have an accepted answer, only a workaround) is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32336944/spring-mvc-complex-object-data-binding -- it looks as though this may not be (easily) achievable, unfortunately.